# Shell script to connect to database on solaris server

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, scripting, solaris

```
var=$(sqlplus -s username/pwd$@SID <<EOF
set heading on
set trimspool off
set linesize 200
set feedback off
SET MARKUP HTML ON
spool output.htmL
SELECT * FROM V$SESSION where username='FSUSER' and PROGRAM='SQL Developer' and OSUSER  NOT IN ('username');
spool off;
exit;
EOF)
echo "$var" > output.txt
exit 0
```

but the output files shows as ORA error , manual connect is working without any issues from same server .

> ERROR: ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
>
> SP2-0306: Invalid option. Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS
> {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM}] [edition=value]] where
>  ::= [/][@<connect_identifier>]
>  ::= [][/][@<connect_identifier>]

Any help here is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

With a here-document (the construction `<<EOF ... EOF`) the end-tag should be the only characters on the line. Therefor replace

```
EOF)
```

with

```
EOF
)
```

Your code has another problem: The `$` in `V$SESSION` is evaluated/parsed, resulting in errors. Parsing can be avoided with a backslash `V\$SESSION` or by putting quotes around your start-tag EOF:

```
var=$(sqlplus -S /nolog << 'EOF'
....
EOF
)
```